# Do I have to place any scripts/modules I create and want to import within the node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, importerror

I am creating a VSCode extension, and following the getting started guide (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) have used yeoman scaffold to get started. I created a new file, *newModule.js* in the same directory and want to import it as a module for use in the main extension.js script. I then do:

```
const newModule = require('./newModule.js');
```

This throws an error:

```
cannot find module 'newModule' require stack: -
```

This problem disappears if I copy my file to the *node_modules* folder created by default. I would like to know what is going on here, and what the best way of handling imports is when working with javascript/Node.js/vs-extensions.

I also notice that *node_modules* folder is not pushed to github by default, why?

Answer (score 1):

The `node_modules` folder is for storing all the code from the libraries and packages you are using. It is excluded from git because it is a waste of space and a distraction to store them all in your versioning-control, as you can just re-download them anytime.

Just put your module in the same `/src` directory, and use the `import` syntax to import it, instead of `require`.

```
import newModule  from './newModule';
```

For example, see how it is done in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/task-provider-sample/src/extension.ts) sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Please instead

```
const newModule = require('./newModule.js');
```

Try this

```
import newModule from './newModule');
//                              ^^ Do not use file extension
```

**Also make sure that the file you are calling is in the same directory**